Rounding problem in my Box Blur code in c
i am trying to box blur a image as an assignment of my course in C language, but in most cases the RGB values from the images are being rounded below the actual level according to my professor.
this is my code :
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Create a copy of image
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    // for every row
    for (int i=0;i<height;i++)
       { // for every pixel
            for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
            {
                // initalising colours
                int blue=copy[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                int red = copy[i][j].rgbtRed;
                int green =copy[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                // initialising turns
                int tblue=1;
                int tred=1;
                int tgreen =1;

                // if the pixel is between top and 2nd last
                if ((i>=0)&&(i<=height-2))
                {
                        // add the values for the pixel below it
                        blue+=copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue;
                        red+=copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed;
                        green+=copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen;
                        // add a turn
                        tblue++;
                        tred++;
                        tgreen++;
                        // if the pixel is between left adn 2nd last
                        if ((j>=0)&&(j<=width-2))
                        {
                            // add the avlue of right side  below it
                            blue+=copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                            red+=copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed;
                            green+=copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                            // add a turn
                            tblue++;
                            tred++;
                            tgreen++;
                        }
                        // if the pixel is between right and 2nd
                        if ((j<=height-1)&&(j>=1))
                        {
                            // add the values of left side below it
                            blue+=copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                            red+=copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed;
                            green+=copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                            // add a turn
                            tblue++;
                            tred++;
                            tgreen++;
                        }
                    }

                // if the pixel is between bottom and 2nd
                if ((i<=height-1)&&(i>=1))
                {
                    // add the values for the pixel above it
                    blue+=copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue;
                    red+=copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed;
                    green+=copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen;
                    // add a turn
                    tblue++;
                    tred++;
                    tgreen++;
                    // if the pixel is between left adn 2nd last
                    if ((j>=0)&&(j<=width-2))
                    {
                        // add the avlue of right side  above it
                        blue+=copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                        red+=copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed;
                        green+=copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                        // add a turn
                        tblue++;
                        tred++;
                        tgreen++;
                    }
                    // if the pixel is between right and 2nd
                    if ((j<=height-1)&&(j>=1))
                    {
                        // add the values of left side above it
                        blue+=copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                        red+=copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed;
                        green+=copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                        // add a turn
                        tblue++;
                        tred++;
                        tgreen++;
                    }
                }
                // if the pixel is between left and 2nd last
                if ((j>=0)&&(j<=width-2))
                {
                    // add the avlue of the one right of it
                    blue+=copy[i][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                    red+=copy[i][j+1].rgbtRed;
                    green+=copy[i][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                    // add a turn
                    tblue++;
                    tred++;
                    tgreen++;
                }
                // if the pixel is between right and 2nd
                if((j<=height-1)&&(j>=1))
                {
                    // add the avlue of the one left of it
                    blue+=copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                    red+=copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed;
                    green+=copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                    // add a turn
                    tblue++;
                    tred++;
                    tgreen++;
                }
                // divide socre by turns and put it in round ()
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue/tblue);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red/tred);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green/tgreen);
            }
    }

    return;
}

in this the height and witdh are the dimensions of the image
and the RGB triple is a two dimeansional array tha stors the RGB values of every pixel of the image
i am trying to box blur it .

blue/tblue is integer division, meaning it will truncate the value to an integer. Cast one of the operands to a floating point value first so the result is floating point and then round will do what it does. round((double)blue/tblue);

OT: no reason to use 3 counters that all increment in unison. You only need 1 counter of the number of pixels contributing to the totals. All this code hides if ((j<=height-1)&&(j>=1))... There's no relationship between j and height... j is related to width.

Suggestion: Carefully rename every instance of the variable i with the name h (short version of "height"), and replace every instance of j with w (short version of "width")... Giving variables meaningful names will dramatically reduce the possibility of this sort of mistake. (Additionally, lowercase i and j are SO easy to mix-up and not notice because of their similar appearance in a small font.)

Or (IMHO) even better: rename i to row and j to col (short for column) because that is what they are used for.
